# No se cargan mis ficheros txt a MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, data

Tengo una consulta creada en `XAMPP` para cargar unos `csv` a `MySQL`, esta es:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\TablasMensuales\02-18 Contabilidad\Contabilidad\CPF_CONBP.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_conbp FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Muestra que se carga, pero no inserta ningún registro y no muestra errores.

Comment: ¿El archivo tiene datos?

Comment: @A.Cedano si, los tiene

Comment: Si es un archivo muy grande esa consulta puede tardar un rato en terminar el proceso.

Comment: no es muy grande, la consulta dice que es satisfactoria y se cargaron 0 filas

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el contenido del archivo si no son datos confidenciales, para ver si está armando como dice la instrucción de `LOAD DATA`?

Comment: el csv? igual son confidenciales

Comment: tenia un sw para cargar datos, pero el cliente lo quiere automatico

Comment: ¿Los campos están separados por `|` y las líneas terminan por `\n`?

Comment: @A.Cedano si es como dices